# JTable limits result set to 4

Tags: java, mysql, jtable

im having a hard time finding where is my mistake so i could use some help.

I'm using 2 tables. "diamerismata", and another one based on which users selects in previous steps, you'll be looking at it as "+KataxDiamTable+".

My query is:

```
            String monthly = "SELECT diamerismata.DIAMERISMA as Διαμέρισμα, diamerismata.ΟΝΟΜΑ as Όνομα, "+KataxDiamTable+".LASTDIFF as ΠρΔιαφορά, "+KataxDiamTable+".ΧΡΕΩΣΕΙΣ as Χρέωση, "+KataxDiamTable+".DATE as Ημερομηνία, "+KataxDiamTable+".DIFF as Διαφορά  FROM diamerismata, "+KataxDiamTable+" WHERE MONTH("+KataxDiamTable+".DATE) = "+ms+" AND YEAR("+KataxDiamTable+".DATE) = "+yr+" AND "+KataxDiamTable+".IDdiam = diamerismata.IDdiam AND ID = ( SELECT MAX(ID) FROM "+KataxDiamTable+" WHERE "+KataxDiamTable+".IDdiam = diamerismata.IDdiam) ORDER BY diamerismata.DIAMERISMA";
```

But it only returns 4 rows when it should be returning 10.

"yr" and "ms" are date filters. But every record of mine has the same date, so the problem isn't there...

IDdiam and ID are ASC and UNIQUE.

Any Ideas? Thank you

Comment: I doubt we could help without the table definition, I guess this is a bad join or condition). NOTE : Please format the query to be readable too. FYI : See what "SQL INJECTION" is !

Comment: When running the query in mysql workbench, it returns the rows it should be returning. When running the program it only returns 4, so somehow my jtable limits the rows

Comment: Well, did you log the rows before adding them to the `JTable` to see the result? Since I don't see any code about that `JTable`, it is impossible for me to help you... Post a [mcve] and then we should be able to help.